# Rect.colliderect cannot detect specific collision

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, rect

I am trying to make a very simple game, here is my full code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#define variables
width, height = 940, 780
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
grey = 87, 87, 87
white = 255, 255, 255
player = pygame.image.load("Pics\goodcar.jpeg")
keys = [False, False, False, False]
playerpos = [0,40]
green = 0,255,0
red = 255,0,0
color = red

x1 = 0
x2 = 40
y1 = 940
y2 = 100




#main program

while 1:

    screen.fill(0)
    road = pygame.draw.rect(screen, grey, (x1,x2,y1,y2), 0)
    traffic_light = pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (640,90), 40, 1)


    screen.blit(player, playerpos)


    car_rect = player.get_rect()


    if traffic_light.colliderect(car_rect):
    print("Its working")



    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_RIGHT:
                keys[0]=True
            elif event.key==K_LEFT:
                keys[1]=True
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                keys[2]=True
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                keys[3]=True


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keys[0]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                keys[1]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                keys[2]=False
            elif event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                keys[3]=False




    if keys[0]==True:
        playerpos[0]+=3
    elif keys[1]==True:
        playerpos[0]-=3
    elif keys[2]==True:
        playerpos[1]+=3
    elif keys[3]==True:
        playerpos[1]-=3
    pygame.display.update()
```

at the part where it checks if the car collided with the traffic light, it doesn't do anything.
Iv'e tried using a try statement, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation what [`Surface.get_rect()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) does:

> Returns a new rectangle covering the entire surface. This rectangle will always start at 0, 0 with a width. and height the same size as the image.

So the `Rects` never collide, since the `Rect` for the car always starts at `0, 0`. An easy fix is to simply set the starting position (`top` and `left`) of the car `Rect` while calling `get_rect()`.

Change

```
car_rect = player.get_rect()
```

to:

```
car_rect = player.get_rect(left=playerpos[0], top=playerpos[1])
```

(Another way is to use the `Sprite` class, which basically combines a `Surface` and a `Rect`.)